# составить список листов из нескольких файлов excel помощью Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

из заданной папки необходимо со всех файлов exсel составить список листов

Comment: что вы хотите получить на выходе - список наименований листов (sheet names)? В виде списка, в виде словаря? Что делать если в файлах множество листов, если есть дупликаты? Приведите пример того, что хотите получить на выходе и, желательно, ваши попытки это реализовать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

In [154]: files = list(Path(r'D:\temp\.data').glob('*.xlsx'))

In [155]: files
Out[155]:
[WindowsPath('D:/temp/.data/2016-08-15-2016-08-21.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('D:/temp/.data/a.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('D:/temp/.data/primer1.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('D:/temp/.data/result.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('D:/temp/.data/test.1.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('D:/temp/.data/test.xlsx')]

In [156]: res = {f.stem:list(pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None).keys()) for f in files}
```

Результат:

```
In [157]: res
Out[157]:
{'2016-08-15-2016-08-21': ['TDSheet'],
 'a': ['TDSheet'],
 'primer1': ['er'],
 'result': ['Sheet1', 'aaa'],
 'test.1': ['Sheet1'],
 'test': ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'AAA']}
```